# Filter behavior with new entries

Tags: filter

let's say I have a table with a column 'Name' and the user has set a column filter for 'Frank'. He currently sees some entries which match his search.
This table is configured to accept new items via in-Table editing. If the user (with active filter) enters a new entry which does NOT match this filter (e.g. an entry with name 'Helen'), should the new entry...

a) be disappearing instantly after the user entered it because it does not match the filter?
**OR**
b) stay visible although it does not match the current filter because the user explicitly entered it and it would be bad UX to pull it away from him?

What do you think? I couldn't find any examples, so I am hoping on some UX advice here.

All the best and have a nice day,
Nadine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter rules should definitely be applied, otherwise look at the data will give the impression that the filter does not work correctly.

However, you are right to be cautious as immediately hiding the record might make the user think that it hasn't added correctly and they might try to do it again and add a duplicate.

I would suggest that you handle this by making it clear that the new record has been added by showing the user a confirmation message.

Also, I would suggest that your application logic checks if the new record is hidden by the filter or not. If it is hidden by the filter, then your confirmation message should also recommend that the user adjusts their filter settings in order to see the new record.

---

**Confirmation Message Design**

I can't really advise on how to design this confirmation message without seeing your application layout, however this could simply be a block of text that appears below the table (near where the user enters the data).

For example, the confirmation message could say (depending on filter) settings:

Message to display when a new record is included in filtered results:

> *A new contact record has been added for Helen.*

Message to display when a new record is not include in filtered results:

> *A new contact record has been added for Helen. You will need to adjust your filter settings to include this new record in the results.*

---

**Summary**

Ensure the filter settings are applied correctly, but inform the user that the new record has been added and they may need to adjust their filter settings before they can see it.