# How to handle data addition in data grid when data is sorted

Tags: design-patterns, info-visualisation, data-tables, sort

I have data grid in application which has pagination and the latest added record is added on top.  If the data is already sorted on a column and another record is added to the table how should the behaviour  be:

1.The sort should be reset and the latest record should be added on top

2.The record should be added to its sorted position in the list

Comment: Although [the question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/133781/130560) may not be exactly the same, the logic in [the answer provided here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/133782/130560) is.

Answer (score 2):

The new record should be added based on the sort order selected. Even if that means that the new record won't be visible on the currently selected page. This is to ensure that the data presented it correct and avoids making it look like your application has a potential issue with sorting.

The obvious concern with this approach is that the user might not realise that the record has been added and might attempt to re-do it thus adding duplicate entries.

To circumvent this issue, when a new record is added, regardless of it's visibility on the page you should inform the user with a confirmation message to show that the record has been successfully added.

You could even take this message a step further and warn the user that depending on the sort order of the grid, the new record might not be immediately visible on the current page. Although I expect the "successfully added" message will suffice.